# python / BeautifulSoup use string value to access an child objet / tag

Tags: python, xml, string, beautifulsoup

I'm using BeautifulSoup to work with XML files in python, in order to process XML files with an structure like that:

```
<xml>
  <headtag>
     <subtag1>textA</subtag1>
     <subtag2>textB</subtag2>
     <anothertag>textC</anothertag>
[...]
```

Now I need to access an specific child object, which normally would look like this:

```
print (BeautifulSoupObject.xml.headtag.subtag1.string)
```

But in my case I have the child object stored in a string, like:

```
objIlikeToGet= 'xml.headtag.subtag1'
```

What I like do to is something like that (pseudocode):

```
print (BeautifulSoupObject.objIlikeToGet.string)
```

So my question: how can I use the string content to direct access the BeautifulSoup-sub-object?

//Btw: why I need this: I have a config-file, where I define some xml subobjects in the `objIlikeToGet` to read only this single information depending on the used config-file. This means one script uses different config-files and returned different informations.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using `eval`. Be sure that the input is coming from you rather than an untrusted source.

```
html = """<xml>
  <headtag>
 <subtag1>textA</subtag1>
 <subtag2>textB</subtag2>
 <anothertag>textC</anothertag>
 </headtag>
 </xml>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml-xml')

objIlikeToGet= "xml.headtag.subtag1"

print(eval("soup." + objIlikeToGet + ".string"))
```

Outputs: `textA`